# Null Reference exception in my property getter

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception, getter

Here is my code:

```
private decimal _WeightedScoreProfitibility;

[PersistentAlias("WeightProfitibility.WeightNumber * ScoreProfitibility.ScoreNumber")]
public decimal? WeightedScoreProfitibility 
{
    get
    {
        try
        {
            return decimal.Parse(EvaluateAlias("WeightedScoreProfitibility").ToString());
        }
        catch ( NullReferenceException )
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

I was getting an Object Null Reference on the my getter. I am assuming because the fields I am calculating in the Persistent Alias are 0 values.

I am catching the null reference error and now when i run the app It just hangs and spins. it never loads. How do I handle this null reference exception when the values I am calculating in the persistent alias are 0?

Comment: `EvaluateAlias("WeightedScoreProfitaibility")` is returning `null`. Find out why using a debugger and fix it. Alternatively, you can check if the value returned is `null` and if it is, do something else. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) for more information.

Comment: Why `decimal?` if you don't return `null`?